# Apply a style to Run objects of a generated TextBlock

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a generated TextBlock with two Run objects inside. I would like to assign a color to the first Run object and another color to the other one, and I'd like to specify this in XAML.

this is the codebehind:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();

tb.Style = Application.Current.Resources["MyTextStyle"] as Style;   
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "Line 1" });
tb.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "Line 2" });

container.Child = tb;
```

and this is the XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="MyTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}" />
</Style>
```

how should I modify the XAML code?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this way?

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Comment}">
    <Run FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red">line1</Run><LineBreak/><Run>line2</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: This seems to be XAML declared TextBlock and not a codebehind generated TextBlock.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if you mean it this way. a) You cannot style a Run object as it does not have Style property. b) You cannot bind Run object as it is not a FrameworkElement. c) Hence the only option I see is to set Foreground from static resources; they can be defined in Xaml.

Comment: For example you can define application resource <SolidColorBrush x:Key="myBrush" Color="Brown"/> and then use it as runBlock.Foreground = (Brush)Application.Current.Resources["myBrush"].